# Not all sub categories coming from model in codeignitrer

Tags: php, view, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter 3, I am facing an issue which is basically I have a page in admin panel for adding categories similarly separate page for adding subcategories which exactly looks like these :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkPos.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iG7lT.png)

that's how my table looks like of main_category :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noCtc.png)

and that's how my table looks like of sub_category :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWT31.png)

So the problem I am facing it in front homepage I want to display my categories in nav and when the user just move his cursor on the respective category it should open drop down for showing subcategory, but my nav is showing only one subcategory when I hover over any category it shows me only first subcategory :

that's how my nav looking now :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKShI.png)

this is the code in my homepage.php view which is creating nav :

```
   <div class="w3-container">
              <div class="w3-bar w3-light-grey">
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Today</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Find Auctions</a>

                <div class="w3-dropdown-hover">

               <?php foreach($sc as $ID):?>

                  <button class="w3-button"><?php echo $ID->mcname?></button>
                  <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-card-4">

                    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" id="<?php echo $ID->sc_id?>">  
                      <?php echo $ID->scname; ?>
                    </a>  
                 </div>
              <?php endforeach;?>   
                </div>
</div>
            </div>
```

and this is the code of my model :

```
  public function getallsubcat()
    {
     $this->db->select('A.sc_id , A.scname , A.featured , A.catid , B.mcname , B.mc_id ' );
     $this->db->from('sub_category as A');
     $this->db->join('main_category as B', 'A.catid = B.mc_id' , 'INNER');
     $query = $this->db->get();
     return $query->result();
    }
```

please help me why it's showing only one subcategory, thanks.

Comment: May be because of this every category has only one subcategory

Comment: no I have multiple categories for arts , also its showing only first subcategory of first category , just that